# Where do facebook like for my website homepage come from?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My website homepage is [Edit Photos For Free](http://editphotosforfree.com).

I use [Facebook Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to see the number of likes for my homepage which is rapidly growing day by day.

But I wonder, I have not put any facebook like button in anywhere, even in my website's homepage. From where those likes came from. The no. of likes just now is  8,470. it's growing rapidly i.e. more than 200-300+ likes per day. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a big deal , you dont have facebook like button on your website but people can search for your page on facebook and google also displays facebook pages in top search results so people can easily get its link and like it .
eg. like if you like ice cream , you can type it on facebook and get to the page and like it , similarly people must be searching for your website and likin

Comment: I am not talking about my facebook or fan page, it's my website homepage that is getting so much facebook likes. I want to know from where those likes comes from because I have not put facebook like button anywhere for my website homepage url.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook not just count liks on Like Button but also count all shares of your website, if someone share on Facebook links to your website Facebook will index this shares as likes.